# How can I create a template in MediaWiki that will autopopulate a portion of itself?

Tags: mediawiki

Basically what I'd like to do is to create a template which when embedded in a wiki page will automatically fill in one part of with the title of the page that you are currently reading.

As an example, if you are reading a page titled ExchangeServer. There would be a template included in that page which would include a URL to link to a service.

Part of that URL includes the name of that wiki page. So I would want it to be something along the lines of:

https://*AutoPopulatedName*:1311

Is there a way to do this? If so, can somebody please explain how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [the `{{PAGENAME}}` magic word](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#Page_names)?

Comment: I think that would be it, yes. Thank you for this. I'll give it a try and award the answer once verified. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using it for URL linking, you probably would want to use `{{FULLPAGENAME}}` which will include the namespace and if you use `{{FULLPAGENAMEE}}` it will also put in the appropriate underscores instead of spaces.